# Multiple declaration of media queries instead of one

Tags: css, media-queries

If I have a media query, such as:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
...
}
```

It would be bad practice to do so many media queries, how many files I have?

For example, I have the file `_button.scss`:

```
.button {
...
}

/**
 * Media query only for .button
 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .button {
        ...
    }
}
```

In another file, `_input.scss`:

```
.input {
...
}

/**
 * Media query only for .input
 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .input {
        ...
    }
}
```

And into the final style file, `style.scss`:

```
@import 'button';
@import 'input;

...
```

Instead of making a single media query, `style.scss`:

```
@import 'button';
@import 'input';

/**
 * Media query for all
 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .button {
        ...
    }

    .input {
        ...
    }
}
```

It is not that long ago that I approached the responsive, so I have many doubts (like this). Thanks to anyone who solves my issue.

---

Update:

In fact, the problem is not simply if it is (or not) a bad practice, but also as regards the performace. I would have a much better result (in performance), or almost indifferent?

Comment: As long as we don't talk about thousands, do what make your code maintainable and easy to follow

Comment: Personally, I don't consider this bad practice at all. I like to keep all my SCSS files separate so I know where each style is. No problem at all with declaring media queries.

Comment: I thinks it's matter of preference. I would keep them in different files, a modular approach it's structured, easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: This seems a matter of opinion / preference, whether it is better to focus on minimizing repetition, or better to focus on managing CSS as modular components.  There are cases for both... As a discussion it is certainly interesting; as a question with a solid answer... not so much.

Comment: This a **primarily opinion based question** *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* It will be closed for sure